# Image uploading using php not working

Tags: php

I was just trying to create a simple image uploading script.

This is what I used, but it seems there is some problem and shows an error

```
<?php
    define("FILEREPOSITORY", "./");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user =$_POST['user'];
        $ext_boo = FALSE;
        $size_boo = FALSE;
        $user_boo = FALSE;
        if(strlen($user)<=0){
            echo "No Username";
            $user_boo = FALSE;
        }
        if($_FILES['picture']['size'] <=1024000){
            $size_boo = TRUE;
        }
        else{
            echo "Too large";
            $size_boo = FALSE;
        }
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'])){
            //mime type
            switch($_FILES['picture']['type']){
                case "image/jpeg":
                    $extension = ".jpeg";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
                case "image/gif":
                    $extension = ".gif";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                    $extension = ".png";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
            }
            if($ext_boo && $size_boo && $user_boo){
                $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY."/images/".$user."".$extension."");
                if($result)
                    echo "Uploaded";
                else
                    echo "Some problems";
            }
        echo "Wrong file type";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<table>
        <form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
        <tr>
        <td>User:</td>
        <td><input type=\"test\" name=\"user\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>File:</td>
        <td><input type=\"file\" name=\"picture\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" />
        </form>
        </table>";
    }
?>
```

Can anybody help me to find out the problem?

**Error after trying `var_dump($_FILES);`:**

```
array (size=1)
  'picture' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'sample.png' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php74BB.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 7575
Wrong file type
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: `$user_boo` never gets true

Comment: @BOMEz Updated the question with the Error statement

Comment: Do a var_dump($_FILES) and see what it says after you test for $_POST['submit']. It seems $_FILES has no index named picture for some reason.

Comment: @BOMEz : It shows `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: Dumb question: Did you actually choose a file to upload? Everything looks OK. Have to commute home now. Will check it out later if no one else jumps in to help.

Comment: @BOMEz: Yes I did. OKay, waiting for a response :)

Comment: Actually there was a small typo here:
`<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">`

Now it shows no error but the image is not getting uploaded. THis is the output for the var_dump($_FILES)

`array (size=1)
  'picture' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'sample.png' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php74BB.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 7575
Wrong file type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `$user_boo` to TRUE anywhere. I switched it to start off as `TRUE` (assume it is true until you later check to see if it's false on line 10).

Also on line 37 I changed the file path. You had an extra `/` in your upload location. Code below worked on my machine. Make sure you have the www user set to owner on whatever location you are trying to upload to and that it has permissions to write.

```
<?php
    define("FILEREPOSITORY", "./");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user =$_POST['user'];
        $ext_boo = FALSE;
        $size_boo = FALSE;
        $user_boo = TRUE;
        if(strlen($user)<=0){
            echo "No Username";
            $user_boo = FALSE;
        }
        if($_FILES['picture']['size'] <=1024000){
            $size_boo = TRUE;
        }
        else{
            echo "Too large";
            $size_boo = FALSE;
        }
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'])){
            //mime type
            switch($_FILES['picture']['type']){
                case "image/jpeg":
                    $extension = ".jpeg";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
                case "image/gif":
                    $extension = ".gif";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                    $extension = ".png";
                    $ext_boo = TRUE;
                    break;
            }
            var_dump($ext_boo,$size_boo,$user_boo);
            if($ext_boo && $size_boo && $user_boo){
                $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY."images/".$user."".$extension."");
                if($result)
                    echo "Uploaded";
                else
                    echo "Some problems";
            }
        echo "Wrong file type";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<table>
        <form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
        <tr>
        <td>User:</td>
        <td><input type=\"test\" name=\"user\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>File:</td>
        <td><input type=\"file\" name=\"picture\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" />
        </form>
        </table>";
    }
?>
```